# In The Matrix Resurrections, how did The Analyst reset situations?

Tags: the-matrix

What happened after the first time Morpheus meets Neo in the bathroom? After they meet, there is a big shootout in the office. How did The Analyst reset everything? He also did this with Neo's suicide attempts, I assume.

Answer (score 0):

As we see in *The Matrix Revolutions* the old Matrix code was perfectly capable of repairing itself when damaged. There's certainly no reason an improved version of the Matrix wouldn't be able to do the same trick.

[image]

Since the bulk of the people had already evacuated by the time the building exploded, it would have been a relatively simple matter to [reset their memories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147677/20774) and put them back to work, leaving Neo none the wiser.