# Why doesn’t Cypher live out his fantasies in test programs?

Tags: the-matrix

I don’t understand why Cypher betrays the resistance. He wants to live out a life where he is rich and important. However, couldn’t he program a test program like Mouse did where he can live out that fantasy? Or is it that he really doesn’t want to know it isn’t real, and only the machines can erase his memory? Could the resistance wipe his memory and put him in a fantasy too? That way he doesn’t have to betray them? I think it seems like a weak plot point that he betrays the resistance just cause he’s tired of the tasteless wheat. Can’t they eat whatever they want in test programs?

Comment: The Zionese rebels are not above using the Construct for sexy fun times; https://youtu.be/h-_8pMHiRnE?si=dBrZFeUZT9N1Npvg

Answer (score 34):

Cypher's goal is to be reinserted into the Matrix **with no memory of reality**. His aim isn't just to eat fake steak, but to eat that fake steak with no realisation that it's fake. He doesn't just want to *fantasise* about being a wealthy and important person, he wants to return to the Matrix and be utterly convinced of it.

> **Cypher:** *You know, I know this steak doesn’t exist. I know that when I put it in my mouth, the Matrix is telling my brain that it is juicy and delicious. After nine years, you know what I realize? **Ignorance is bliss.***
>
> **Agent Smith:** **Then we have a deal?**
>
> **Cypher:** ***I don’t want to remember nothing. Nothing.** You understand? And I want to be rich. You know, someone important. Like an actor.*

We don't really know whether the Zionese rebels can control memories in the [same ways that the Machines can](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/147677/20774), but given that their shtick is '*we're going to show you the truth*', I'd imagine that even if they could influence someone's mind in that way, they wouldn't.

Comment: And it's not just the food that he despises, it's the fact that he lives in a shitty dystopia, in constant fear for his life, ignored by the woman he loves.

Comment: I was just about to write a similar answer, but you beat me to it. +1

Comment: @TitaniusAnglesmith - If you think you've got anything else to add, feel free to suggest it. Or you can still write your own answer if you have a different take.

Comment: I don't, really. You've covered what I had, and your quote is more complete than what I was going to add. Just out of curiosity, and please don't take this the wrong way, do you have an eidetic memory? ;)

Comment: @TitaniusAnglesmith - It's a film series that I know a considerable amount about. I've certainly read and viewed every single *in-universe* source including the films, games, comics, prose stories and the animatrix short films. I've also worked my way through the various versions of the scripts, making-of featurettes, movie website, cast and crew interviews, video games, etc. etc.

Comment: I'm just truly fascinated by your extensive knowledge about almost anything sci-fi. I hope you weren't offended by my question. I had no such intent. Your knowledge, and the speed and willingness with which you share it are impressive.

Comment: @TitaniusAnglesmith - I've found that studios often produce a wealth of additional materials for shows and films that are popular. The key is to immerse yourself in *everything* licenced, then develop your own opinions on what's actually 'canon' or not.

Comment: I think, there is one important aspect missing. Cypher’s motivation is not just to improve his own life. He thinks, Morpheus lied to him, as he promised to set him free, but instead, he found himself under military command of Morpheus “*You call this ‘free’? All I do is what he tells me to do.*” and wants revenge “*God, I wish I could be there, when they break ya. I wish I could be there just when it happens, so right then, you'd know it was me.*”

Comment: Is Zion**ese** the official name for the humans in Zion? I would have assumed Zion**ist**, though maybe that's too associated with the movement. There is this [area in Pennsylvania](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zion,_Pennsylvania) which appears to use the latter but it's the only geographic location with the name for which Wiki lists a demonym.

Comment: @user170231 - Zionese is *my* term for them. In the films and other works they aren't really referred to as anything in particular. ([q.v. Naboobians](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Naboo_(people)))

Answer (score 4):

Humanity wouldn't let him.  While the rest of humanity is living on gruel, he wants to live his entire life in a virtual reality?    Maintaining and powering a computer just so one person can live out their fantasies would be seen as ridiculous.   And if he asked for it or else he would turn them over to the machines, they'd probably execute him for treason on the spot.

Maybe they could hook him up and get energy from him like the Matrix does to at least account for the power.   I always thought that was silly, but even if not there must be some efficiency to having multiple people share the reality that is being ran as a program.   Zion is fighting for their lives and freedom for all humanity.  They wouldn't waste vital resources.

Also they don't have sophisticated AIs, everyone in his reality would just be a simple program.   Maybe they could walk and talk, but probably not hold a conversation.  Not much of a life eating steak alone for the rest of your life.

Lastly, Agent Smith said the AIs originally tried to build a paradise, but the human minds needed conflict and rebelled.  If he was living in his own paradise he would probably end up rebelling again and disconnecting from the system.